# jQuery UI Dialog - halt close event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a way to stop a close event for a jQuery UI Dialog?

I have a dialog modal with a form.  When the user closes the dialog, I'd like to prompt "Continue without saving changes?" [Yes] [No].  The [Yes] button continues and closes the dialog as expected. The [No] button will stop the close event and keep the dialog open.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `beforeClose` option. From the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/):

> This event is triggered when a dialog attempts to close. If the beforeClose event handler (callback function) returns false, the close will be prevented.
>
> Code examples
>
> Supply a callback function to handle the beforeClose event as an init option.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   beforeClose: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Comment: I saw this before but didnt think to use it for what I needed. It really helped! If anybody is curious `$(ele).dialog("close")` returns the value of beforeClose. I had a function that did a lot of other work after it was closed and I needed to check/return on the dialog("close") call too.

Answer (score 7):

Justin answer works fine to show the modal. If you want to cancel the closing, your function should return false, like that:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   beforeClose: function(event, ui) 
    { return check_if_unsaved_changes(..); }
});
```

check_if_unsaved_changes should return true if the dialog should close and false if it should not close.

Comment: I'd wondered if the return value was how to cancel, but wasn't sure.  It would be nice if the docs showed an example of canceling or not canceling rather than just mentioning it.  This helped.